# Angular *ngFor item changes

Tags: angular

I have a *ngFor inside another *ngFor. The problem happens when the object used in the other *ngFor changes. Let's say this is our data:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'First parent',
    children: [
      {id: 1, name: 'child1', val: ['1', '2']},
      {id: 2, name: 'child2', val: ['3', '4']}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Second parent',
    children: [
      {id: 3, name: 'child3', val: ['5', '6']},
      {id: 4, name: 'child4', val: ['7', '8']}
    ]
  }
];
```

Now, displaying this data like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let parent of data">
  <h3>{{parent.name}}</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
    <div (click)="childClicked(parent, child)">
      <span>Name: {{child.name}}</span>
      <span>Value: {{child.val}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

childClicked:

```
const newData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Some parent',
    children: []
  }
];


function childClicked(parent, child) {
  const newParent = newData.filter(p => p.id === parent.id)[0];
  if (newParent.children.filter(c => c.id === child.id).length === 0) {
    newParent.children.push(child);
    newParent.children[0].val = [];
  }
}
```

Note! This is a mockup similar to the code I have, but there's too much code and a few requests to get the data, so it's easier to describe the problem this way.

Now, when adding child to its new parent, the child's value changes in the HTML. When adding, we're writing "newParent.children[0].val = [];", because the values the child had before only exist in the old parent.

**How to make the HTML still display the old values (child.val)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose. Either the two parents share the exact same child, and modifying one modifies the other (since it's the exact same child), or the new parent contains a new child, whose state is similar to the state of the first one, except it has an empty array of vals.

Your code is using the first option, but apparently you want the second one. So you need to make a (partial) copy of the child:

```
if (newParent.children.filter(c => c.id === child.id).length === 0) {
  val newChild = {
    id: child.id,
    name: child.name,
    val: []
  };
  newParent.children.push(newChild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

by makeing

```
newParent.children.push(child);
```

you are copying the old children by reference and not by value. It is not a new children, but a reference to the old children. And when you make:

```
newParent.children[0].val = [];
```

you are also deleting the values of the old children.

If you want to retain those, and you want to create new different children, you should make a new object, like with Object.assign:

```
let newChildren = Object.assign({}, child);
newParent.children.push(newChildren);
newParent.children[0].val = [];
```